# mysql, Get all rows which satisfies the group by condition

Tags: mysql, sql, json

My rows looks like -

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1254,
        "receive_date": "2022-11-03T18:30:00.000Z",
        "receive_time": "19:29:00",
        "machineId": "TEST",
        "attributeId": "connection_status",
        "hardwareId": "5"
    },
    {
        "id": 1255,
        "receive_date": "2022-11-03T18:30:00.000Z",
        "receive_time": "19:29:00",
        "machineId": "TEST",
        "attributeId": "connection_status",
        "hardwareId": "6"
    },
    {
        "id": 1256,
        "receive_date": "2022-11-03T18:30:00.000Z",
        "receive_time": "19:30:00",
        "machineId": "TEST",
        "attributeId": "connection_status",
        "hardwareId": "6"
    }
]
```

First I want to group the data by following fields -

1. day of year - column `receive_date` - datatype is `DATE`
2. minutes - column `receive_time` - datatype is `TIME`

After grouping, I want data that satisfies the grouping to be under one attribute.

I want something similar to following as the result of query.

```json
[
    {
        "receive_date": "2022-11-03T18:30:00.000Z",
        "receive_time": "19:29:00",
        "data": [
            {
                "attributeId": "connection_status",
                "hardwareId": "5",
                "value": 478
            },
            {
                "attributeId": "connection_status",
                "hardwareId": "6",
                "value": 344
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "receive_date": "2022-11-03T18:30:00.000Z",
        "receive_time": "19:30:00",
        "data": [
            {
                "attributeId": "connection_status",
                "hardwareId": "6",
                "value": 789
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: *My rows looks like* Please provide this as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO. Now, for example, you tell "column receive_date - datatype is DATE", but the data shown is not legal date value from MySQL looking point.

Comment: SQL is like spreadsheets. It deals in rectangular arrays of data: rows and columns. The nested data structure you propose here is best constructed by your software that talks to SQL. You haven't told us anything about that software (language, etc) so it's not possible to give you good advice about that.

Comment: *After grouping, I want data that satisfies the grouping to be under one attribute.* Why you group `receive_date` and `receive_time` data but do not group the same value in `attributeId`?